# Deleting rows in CSV files using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Relatively new to Pandas so I apologize in advance if this is redundant. I have successfully sorted data in my CSV file, but I would like to delete all the rows for which I no longer need. For example here, I would like to keep rows where trade date and settle date are the same but delete rows for which they are different.

```
Trade Date      Settle Date     Security
 8/15/2017         8/15/2017           a
9/7/2017            9/11/2017          b
8/31/2017          9/6/2017            c
```

I am guessing I need to add True False Booleans but the code I used to try that did not seem to work for me. Any help is appreciated.

```
booleans=[]
for length in df_new:
    if 'Trade Date'=='Settle Date':
    booleans.append(True)
else:
   booleans.append(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[df['Trade Date'] == df['Settle Date']]
df

  Trade Date Settle Date Security
0  8/15/2017   8/15/2017        a
```